# Adding TextView to Layout programmatically using for loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, android-linearlayout

So I was following Google's Android Basics course from Udacity. In one of the lessons inside onCreate method they made ArrayList of Strings and added values from "one" to "ten". After that they made LinearLayout variable and with for loop added TextViews to that layout. This is how whole code looks like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("one");
        words.add("two");
        // ...
        words.add("ten");

        LinearLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.root_view);

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
            wordView.setText(words.get(i));
            rootView.addView(wordView);
        }
    }
```

They didn't explain, how exactly we can add ten TextViews to layout with same name "wordView" inside for loop?

Comment: `wordView` is just the variable name, not the id that goes on `android:id` as if you are creating them on your xml. That's just a way to create views BUT you can't reference them after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @javdromero said in the comment, `wordView` is just a reference for the `TextView` View Object. We are just creating a `TextView` object. Setting the text on it and adding it to the `rootView`. `rootView` is just a reference name for the `LinearLayout` in your example. None if the reference names will set the id for the View Objects. The scope of `wordView` is limited to every loop while doing the for loop iteration, once the index increments you are having another View Object reference being assigned to `wordView`.